# Как вывести ошибку из контроллера?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть поле в представлении, которое передает количество добавляемых товаров в метод контроллера:
`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Добавить в корзину" />`
Вот сам метод для добавления в корзину в контроллере:

```
 public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int phoneId, string returnUrl, string quantity)
    {
        Phone phone = repository.Phones
            .FirstOrDefault(g => g.PhoneId == phoneId);

        if (phone != null)
        {
            if (phone.Count >= Convert.ToInt32(quantity))
            {
                cart.AddItem(phone, Convert.ToInt32(quantity));
            }
            else 
            {
               /* Сюда нужен код */
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });}
```

В этом методе должно проверяться значение Count объекта phone: если оно больше или равно запрашиваемому количеству, то идет перенаправление в представление корзины, а иначе пользователю выдается сообщение об ошибке
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом можно реализовать вывод ошибки из контроллера?

Comment: Ну верните код 500 с сообщением об ошибке

Comment: `RedirectToAction("ErrorNoProduct")`